# z-index being overwritten somewhere

Tags: jquery, html, css, z-index

http://alexruimy.com/tll3/

if you type into the search bar, you will see the search results box slide down.

for some reason (it didn't do this before!) the search results box is going behind the grey picture box instead of over it.

i have tried:
 - setting the containing div's z-index to 999 !important in style.css
 - same thing on function call via js
 - lowering the zindex of the grey box behind it.

to no avail. happy to provide more code if necessary. i feel like this will be a quick fix once i realize where i screwed up.

thanks!

Comment: You need to give that box a position in order for it to follow z-index rules. Try adding "position: relative"

Comment: You should at least add to the searchbox: `autocomplete="off"` because like this 2 result boxes open: http://screencast.com/t/MeCQ6gYQC8

Comment: `z-index` only works with `position:...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebug is your friend for things like this. If you don't use Firebug, take some time to learn it as it will save you countless headaches down the road.

As for your issue, the current div covering your drop down has a z-index of 10. Your drop down, while having a z-index of 1000, is contained in a parent div that does not have a z-index set. The fix is to give the parent div a z-index:

```
#header {z-index: 11}
```

Comment: brilliant, thank you! i tried firebug for this but i didn't know the thing about the parent div.